# Passing a parameter to a webhook

Tags: twilio

Want to pass and retrieve a query string to my twilio webhook.

http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/TwilioWebhookTraffic/TwilioWebHookTraffic.aspx/TrafficCallBack?GCAcctNbr=667118358011603

which returns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="./TrafficCallBack?GCAcctNbr=667118358011603" id="form1">
                <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="4PSLlcjmwjYT0iXthm7eB3EX5v8lZY62GKDxWDdNDuZndwHLxahDzcX2H0NFNQX+2NAe7hPownCNYxJJVZJreGwJpqZ/Cwm3f2EIiLGFQ4c=" />
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR" value="CFB6114E" />
            <div>
            TWILIO TRAFFIC REMINDER WEBHOOK ASPX PAGE</div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But does not run the webhook code.

if the URL is just:
http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/TwilioWebhookTraffic/TwilioWebHookTraffic.aspx
then the code is run. but, of course I need the query string.

Comment: Can you clarify your call flow and what Twilio products you are using? Twilio consumes Twilio Markup Language from a Webhook. It is not clear why you would be posting information to a Twilio Webhook? TwiML™ for Programmable Voice - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml

Comment: Yeah, as Alan said, we could do with a few more details here. What are you actually trying to achieve with this? And where are you setting this webhook URL and what do you mean when you say that your webhook code doesn't run?